# How to remove my Birthday from my calendar

Tags: google-calendar

How do I remove my birthday from my Google calendar?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove the birthday from your entry in your [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com).

Unfortunately, Google requires a setting in [My Account](https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/birthday) to control access to certain age-restricted material. (See also [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27442?visit_id=636720417322259575-4126670552&p=birthday&rd=2).)

You can, of course, control who can see that from your [About Me](https://aboutme.google.com/) page.